# FieldType.Number is capping the edit value to 100, any value more than 100 is automatically changed to 100

Tags: shieldui

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. In popup edit of Shield UI all the values that are entered FieldType.Number seems to have a upper limit of 100. Every value more than 100 gets automatically changed to 100.

There seem to be only 4 types String, boolean, data & number. The number seems to limit the max to 100 on edit and add.Even any decimal values are being rounded off automatically and their website is not providing much help on the issue because demo grid views on website are showing similar behaviour

```
Fields("empNumber", fb => fb.Path("empNumber").Type(ShieldUI.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataSource.FieldType.Number))
```

I'm looking for a way to add values more than 100 as well as decimal point for prices. Any help or suggestions in this regard are much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. However I found the following workaround. I have set the grid fieldtype to string instead of number. When editing or creating the grid a javascript is started that calls the controller method through ajax call. In my controller method I take the "string" value and convert it to an int like so:

```
propertyOfModel = Convert.ToInt32(stringParameterFromGrid);
```

That works for me, let me know if you need more help.